# Google Chrome does ot load anymore

Tags: 22.04, google-chrome

Since I updated my system 22.04 with the latest kernel, Chrome does not start anymore. When I click on the Chrome icon, the little black wheel is turning showing some activity for about 30 seconds then disapear. I tried to purge chrome and to clean the cache but nothing change. If I try to start it from a terminal typing google-chrome-stable, I get a message about check failed: : permission not allowed (13). I installed Chromium as a backup and it is working fine but all my shrtcuts and passwords are stores in chrome...
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: if you logged into a Google account in Chrome, your passwords and such are probably stored on your Google account. Check out passwords.google.com, and your bookmarks are stored in a "bookmarks" file (which can be imported into chromium)

Comment: Despite the help received, Chrome still does not load... Maybe I did something else that skewed up the permissiosn. This is teh message I get trying to start from terminal:
regis@regis-desktop:~/Bureau$ google-chrome-stable
[42400:42400:0705/085443.881575:FATAL:credentials.cc(127)] Check failed: . : Permission non accordée (13)
Trappe pour point d'arrêt et de trace (core dumped)

Comment: Thank you for yoru help. It is true that I can access my password with the google adress but after that, Chrome does not sync with my other computers... So, I need Chrome anyway. But your help did allow mer tio access this account using my Ubuntu computer.

Answer (score 0):

try to reinstall chrome

```
sudo apt reinstall google-chrome-stable
```

or update chrome

```
sudo apt update google-chrome-stable
```

**update:**

remove chrome

```
sudo dpkg -r google-chrome-stable
```

install chrome

```
sudo apt install google-chrome-stable
```

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I had already try to reinstall from the deb file and tried again with the sudo apt install command. This does not change anything....

Comment: @RegisEga look at update in my answer

Comment: The sudo apt update google-chrome-stable doesn't work on Ubuntu 22.04 it gives an error "The update command takes no arguments"

Comment: see this answer https://askubuntu.com/a/1477452/1698042